# How to solve infinite readLine while

Tags: java, file, netbeans

I have a program and one of the methods I use is for counting the lines a .txt file has and return an integer value. The problem is when I execute it, despite I wrote if my line is == null the while has to stop, the while loop keeps going, ignoring the nulls it gets infinitely.

I don't know what to do to try to solve it.

```
private int sizeOfFile (File txt) {
    FileReader input = null;
    BufferedReader count = null;
    int result = 0;
    try {
        
        input = new FileReader(txt);
        count = new BufferedReader(input);
        
        while(count != null){
        String line = count.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        result++;
        }
        
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            input.close();
            count.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

It has to stop when it detects a null, which means there are no more lines, but it keeps going.

Comment: the System.out.println(line); was to check if the file had that many lines he kept going but it didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you instantiate a `BuffereReader` assign it to `count`, `count` will always be non-null and hence will satisfy the while loop:

```
count = new BufferedReader(input); //count is holding an instance of BufferedReader.

while(count != null){ //here count is non-null and while loop is infinite and program never exits.
```

Instead use the following code, where the each line will be read and checked whether it is null, if null then the program will exit.:

```
input = new FileReader(txt);
count = new BufferedReader(input);
String line = null;
while(( line = count.readLine())!= null){ //each line is read and assigned to the String line variable.
        System.out.println(line);
        result++;
 }
```

If you are using JDK-1.8 you can shorten your code using the `Files` API:

```
int result = 0;
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(txt.getAbsolutePath()))) {
      //either print the lines or take the count.
      //stream.forEach(System.out::println); 
      result = (int)stream.count(); 
} catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`count` is your `BufferedReader`, your loop should be on `line`! Like,

```
String line = "";
while (line != null) {
    line = count.readLine();
```

Also, you should use [`try-with-Resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to `close` your resources (instead of the `finally` block). And you could write that `while` loop more idiomatically. Like,

```
private int sizeOfFile(File txt) {
    int result = 0;
    try (BufferedReader count = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txt))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = count.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            result++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```